# Importing the numpy c-extensions failed

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, miniconda

#### Importing the numpy c-extensions failed

I installed *python 3.7* on my windows system to work on ***visual studio code***. Everything was going well, including using the libraries.
I uninstalled python using the *uninstalling program tool in control panel*. And installed ***Miniconda 3***.
I checked that everything works well, and then installed the numpy library using `conda install numpy` in my terminal ***GitBash*** on ***windows 10***, then checked it on my visial studio code, but it failed to start.

#### Reproducing code example:

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[-1], [7], [-26]])
```

#### Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\ramim\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py",
>   line 17, in 
>       from . import multiarray   File "C:\Users\ramim\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py",
>   line 14, in 
>       from . import overrides   File "C:\Users\ramim\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import ( ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:/Users/ramim/Desktop/22/Matrix library/alsf.py", line 3, in
>   
>       import numpy as np   File "C:\Users\ramim\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy__init__.py", line
>   142, in 
>       from . import core   File "C:\Users\ramim\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core__init__.py",
>   line 47, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError:
>
> IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
>
> Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
>   - Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
>   - If you have already done that, then:
>     1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "C:\Users\ramim\Miniconda3\python.exe",
>        and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
>        interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.17.3" you're trying to use.
>     2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
>        https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
>        - how you installed Python
>        - how you installed numpy
>        - your operating system
>        - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
>        - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log
>
> - If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`   (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
>
> Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
>   an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.
>
> Original error was: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.

#### Numpy/Python version information:

Python 3.7.5
Numpy 1.17.3

I tried to uninstall and install the numpy library again, but it was useless.
***Note:*** when I type in the teminal `conda install numpy`, it says:

> All requested packages already installed

That's how I checked if numpy is really installed!

***How to solve that?***

Comment: Did your conda environment that you installed into activate before you began executing your code?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and it seems to be a VS Code issue. I am able to run my code from anaconda prompt with no issues. ```conda list``` shows that it's installed. Will submit an answer if I find the problem.

Answer (score 62):

Try to uninstall numpy and setuptools first:

1. `pip uninstall -y numpy`
2. `pip uninstall -y setuptools`
3. `pip install setuptools`
4. `pip install numpy`

Borrowed from solution provided by mehdiHadji here- https://github.com/ipython/ipyparallel/issues/349

Comment: This worked fine for me, but for unknown reasons I had to repeat the two uninstall commands, since two versions of both tools were installed.

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: Worked for homebrew M1 installation

Answer (score 25):

Not sure this is a thing in Visual Studio too, but for Eclipse I had to change one of the environmental variables.

Setup: Windows, Python 3.7, Conda venv with numpy

Solution:

```
CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1
```

For Eclipse, the environment variables can be accessed via Properties -> Run/Debug Settings -> Edit -> Environment.

Anaconda also documented the fix, albeit for a different problem:
[Conda Troubleshooting](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#numpy-mkl-library-load-failed)

Comment: This is also the official solution in the conda official website. I think this should be the selected answer. I had this problem in VS Code and this solved the issue.

Comment: This got me over a HUGE pain with Numpy. This should be the accepted answer imho.

Comment: This one solved my problem. For windows, in the anaconda prompt do `setx CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE 1`. `setx` is used to set an environment variable permanently. If you don't want to change it permanently, then use `set CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1` , this will work for that session only.

Comment: Thanks, I added `CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE` environment variable to windows using GUI and set `Value` as `1` and it worked. I think this should be the correct solution.

Comment: Also fixed Intellij/PyCharm

Answer (score 22):

Similar with my problem recently. I'm using Python 3.8 by Miniconda on Win 10 system. I solved the problem by changing default terminal from PowerShell to Command Prompt.

Steps:

1. Open VS Code's Command Palette menu by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P or F1
2. Choose "Terminal: Select Default Profile" entry
3. Then pick "Command Prompt" option
4. Restart VS Code

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! Thanks!

Comment: I had to close all old terminal sessions so that a new one is created using the default.

Comment: This works on windows 11, Python 3.8 in VSCode. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

This issue is caused by VScode default terminal (powershell) setting,
To switch VScode default terminal from powershell to cmd, the conda env will be activated correctly, other powershell will try to invoke `conda activate xxxxxx` which will fail, then the subsequent `import numpy` will fail.

So two ways to fix it:

1. Fix path search issue under powershell environment to get `conda activate xxxxxx` successfully executed;
2. Change vs code default terminal to 'cmd':
   add "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" in settings.json

Comment: This fixed it for me! Did have to change the backlashes though: ```"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe"```

Comment: using `conda init`  in cmd solved the problem for me

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by reinstalling NumPy through pip:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by the following steps-

1. Uninstalling numpy and pandas with conda
2. Installing numpy and pandas with pip

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by removing ALL numpy versions

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip3 uninstall numpy
```

And then installing numpy and libatlas-base-dev via apt-get

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-numpy
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's something wrong with your `%PATH%`. It might either contain some conflicts, or just be too long (>2047 chars). Try adding the folder with the dlls (from the environment you're trying to use) to the very beginning of it:

```
PATH=C:\Users\ramim\Miniconda3\Library\bin;%PATH%
python -c "import numpy"
```

(based on [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12957#issuecomment-462651814))

Answer (score 1):

For those scratching their head wondering why re-installing `numpy` module works:

If you are using a virtual environment (say in a relative location called `env`), make sure that folder does not make it to other platforms like Docker, or different OS you might be switching to.

Remember the compilation of Python and C extensions necessary for numpy are platform dependent. So if it works in Windows, it will not work in Linux using the same virtual environment (cached modules).

For example, this is particularly important if you are running your code on Windows - and then try to run it on a Linux container via Docker Desktop. (Make sure `env` - or whatever your virtual env is called - is ignored and not copied onto the container)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and tried several of the solutions given here, but none worked for me. I looked in another forum and was able to solve the problem (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13252):

`conda uninstall numpy`

`pip3 install numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check both of these (your PATH or PYTHONPATH environment variables) carefully to see if they are what you expect.

In my case, there was an issue related to updated versions of python and NumPy, I resolved both problems by running a single command over conda PowerShell prompt i.e. conda update --all

Here are the steps-

1. Open Anaconda Powershell Prompt and click 'run as Administrator'.
2. Enter the following code into the prompt and click enter: conda update --all ...

You are all set to run your script

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the other answers here is that they want you to essentially upgrade some version of your packages (i.e. `pip install --upgrade numpy` will upgrade your numpy to the latest)... but what if you have a hard requirement to stay at the current version you are already at?

Some of the answers will work, but only if you *separately* install the numpy dependencies *after* the rest of your dependencies. If you are attempting to set this up from scratch (i.e with `python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt` in a new virtual environment), you will run into this error *until* you also run `python3 -m pip install numpy==<the older version of numpy you need>`, after having initially installed your dependencies. Which essentially installs some dependencies twice or needlessly separates them into two commands, and is not ideal.

When this happens, the root issue is that some package in the pip cache causes the incorrect mixture of C compile libs... and that will keep happening on every new install, until you clear the pip cache...

If you run `python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt` (with your numpy defined in the requirements.txt), and that works, but it does not after removing the `--no-cache-dir` option, then the cache dir is the problem.

Simply run `python3 -m pip cache purge` to clear the wheel packages, then re-run `python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`. Now the packages will install correctly on the first try every time.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is still ongoing. I use VS code with conda venv, and solved it in a similar way with marineCoder:

- In addition to numpy and pandas, I also remove matplotlib using `conda uninstall`
- Cautiously reinstall pandas and numpy using `pip install`

In my case, the error shows up whenever matplotlib package is installed, so I got to either remove it or downgrade the three of them. There is a clash on numpy dependency. Another related issue is shown in this post:

[I get `No module named _multiarray_umath` when using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153886/i-get-no-module-named-multiarray-umath-when-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to manually 'conda activate myenv' the desired environment in the VS code terminal. Previously, I only had to select the python version from the desired environment, and then the environment would auto-activate. This answer references and confirms Brett Cannon's comment above, which was the sole reason I thought to try it.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm on MacOS (with an M1 CPU) I realize my answer is not exactly an answer to the poster's question but as I got the same error and Google sent me here perhaps this helps someone.

In my case I found the error was caused because VSCode was still running in Intel-X86 mode on my Mac-M1. Simply re-installing VSCode using the latest "Mac Universal" distribution switched it to ARM64 mode fixing the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Uninstalled anaconda and installed latest version** 
I tried the answers here but they didn't work for me, uninstalled older version of anaconda (don't remember previous version number now) and installed Anaconda3-2022.05 (Anaconda Navigator 2.1.4). This sorted it for me. I hadn't used my anaconda setup in long time and thus didn't care if my preinstalled packages get wiped out. This took a lot less time and saved from pain of trying more approaches. 
OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I hit this error while running a block of code in a `.ipynb` Jupyter Notebook file.

I fixed the problem by switching the version of Python that was running.  Specifically, I was running Python `3.8.5` from the `Anaconda3` directory on my computer and I switched this to Python `3.9.2` that I had installed elsewhere on my computer.

To toggle the version of Python in VSCode while working on a `.ipynb` file, click on the version specified in the top-right corner of the screen. Thereafter, a dropdown menu will allow you to select from different versions of Python installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by: pip uninstall <module_name> 
For example: `pip uninstall numpy` , You need to do it twice. 
Then install it: `pip install numpy` 
The last error is in Matplotlib, do as before for numpy.
Remember to uninstall twice because the module is installed using pip and conda.

This is how I solved my problem after 2 hours googling and binging.

Comment: This error happened after I used conda-forge. Conda installed modules over the pip virtual env ones.

Answer (score -1):

For my situation, I had updated the version of python that I was using. Running `git clean -xdf` resolved the issue.

My system:

- OS: Mac OS 11.6
- Python: 3.7.8 => 3.8.12
- Numpy: 1.20.2
- Poetry: 1.1.6