# Not able to import numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pip

> {"error": "ImportError('\n\nIMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE
> ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!\n\nImporting the numpy C-extensions
> failed. This error can happen for\nmany reasons, often due to issues
> with your setup or how NumPy was\ninstalled.\n\nWe have compiled
> some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:\n\n
> [https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html\\n\\nPlease](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html%5C%5Cn%5C%5CnPlease)
> note and check the following:\n\n  * The Python version is:
> Python3.9 from "/var/lang/bin/python3"\n  * The NumPy version is:
> "1.24.1"\n\nand make sure that they are the versions you
> expect.\nPlease carefully study the documentation linked above for
> further help.\n\nOriginal error was: No module named
> \'numpy.core._multiarray_umath\'\n')"}

I have installed numpy by the this command
`pip3 install numpy --target .`

I have tried changing numpy and python versions, but same issue exits for me

Comment: The same question has been https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868528/importing-the-numpy-c-extensions-failed

Answer (score -1):

Start using virtual environments (https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/)

### Clean your system Python

```
$ pip freeze > foo.txt
$ pip uninstall -rf foo.txt
$ rm foo.txt
```

### Set up the virtual environment

```
$ python -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install numpy
```

### Import `numpy`

```
$ python

>> import numpy
```